# Why does training loss increase in my Pytorch Linear regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression, loss-function, mse

I'm trying to train a linear regression model with pytorch and use the code from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-with-pytorch-eb6dedead817). I made several changes to the original code: 1. change the datasize `n_data` from 11 to 1e5, 2. decrease the learning rate to 1e-8, 3. to enforce the model trained on batches w/ fixed `batch_size=128`.

```
class linearRegression(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputSize, outputSize):
        super(linearRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(inputSize, outputSize)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out

def linear_demo():
    # create dummy data for training
    n_data = 100000
    x_values = [i for i in range(n_data)]
    x_train = np.array(x_values, dtype=np.float64)
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)

    #y_values = [2*i + 1 + (np.random.rand(1)-0.5)*5 for i in x_values]
    y_values = [2*i + 1 for i in x_values]
    y_train = np.array(y_values, dtype=np.float64)
    y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)

    inputDim = 1        # takes variable 'x'
    outputDim = 1       # takes variable 'y'
    learningRate = 1e-8
    epochs = 10
    batch_size = 128

    model = linearRegression(inputDim, outputDim).to(torch.float64)
    ##### For GPU #######
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model.cuda()
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean').cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learningRate)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        permutation = torch.randperm(n_data)
        idx = permutation[:batch_size]
        # Converting inputs and labels to Variable
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train[idx]).cuda())
            labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train[idx]).cuda())
        else:
            inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train[idx]))
            labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train[idx]))
        # Clear gradient buffers because we don't want any gradient from previous epoch to carry forward, dont want to cummulate gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # get output from the model, given the inputs
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # get loss for the predicted output
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        if loss.item() > 100:
            print(loss)
        # get gradients w.r.t to parameters
        loss.backward()

        # update parameters
        optimizer.step()

        if (epoch % 10 == 0):
            print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
    return
```

However, the above code results in increasing training loss.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EpwK.png)

I tried the following: 1. decrease `n_data` to `1e4`, 2. decrease `learningRate` to `1e-10`. Each alone can ensure the training loss decreasing.
However I don't understand why the datasize and learning rate together increases the training loss since the batch_size is fixed and the training block has no idea how large the dataset is. Can anyone explain why training loss depends on datasize given fixed batch size in this linear regression model?

Comment: Your loss is over billions, you have a different problem, did you normalize inputs and outputs?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy It works after I scale both X and Y. Thanks!

Comment: Normalization is always a basic step in ML, just for the future readers.